# RewriteRule not working .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /brand.php?brand=$1 [L]
```

index.php

```
<a href="/brand.php?brand=audi">audi</a>
```

brand.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['brand'])) {
        echo "brand is ".$_GET['brand'];
    } else {
        echo "no brand selected";
    }
?>
```

according to http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php it should be working.

When you click the link, your url will look like `domain/brand.php?brand=audi`. But I want it to look like `domain/audi/`. It works fine, so I thought. But when you type domain/asdvasdvasdvkasdv/, it will just say: *brand is asdvasdvasdvkasdv* instead of *no brand selected*, since there was never a brand posted to brand.php.

*Apache running on linux with mysql version 10.1.22-MariaDB*

Comment: Don’t you mean `$_POST['brand']`?

Comment: You know, I tried your linked web site, and I can’t get the same rewrite rule you have.

Comment: You cant **$_POST** get requests.

Comment: @starkeen thank you. This was indeed one problem. Noobie mistake :p But still the `RewriteRule` does not work...

Comment: Can you explain your RewriteRule problem clearly? What url are you going to how its not working?

Comment: @starkeen I hope I made my question is clearer now

Comment: Your rule works fine for me. If i type **example.com/foobar/** rule internally forwards it to **/brand.php?brand=foobar** and result on the php file is **brand is foobar**

Comment: Do you mean to redirect ugly url to clean url? **brand.php?brand=foobar** to **/foobar**

Comment: @starkeen exactly like that!

Comment: You can avoid this additional `RewriteRule` by just issuing the proper URL in the first place, e.g. index.php: `<a href="/audi/">audi</a>`

Comment: Concretize the rule with alternatives `^(audi|bmw|opel)/$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed

There are a couple of ways to fix this problem, but I think this is the best one:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^brand/([^/]*)/$ /brand.php?brand=$1 [L]
```

html

```
<a href="/brand/audi/">audi</a>
```

You will need to link to a subdirectory `/brand/` which represents brand.php. In brand.php you will simply check if the value of brand is in the database.

You will need to link to /brand/brandname/ in order to get brand.php. If you use `/brand.php?brand=brandame` as a link, the URL will not be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewriteRule only maps **/bradname/** to the old url **/brand.php?brand=brandname** .  To redirect your old url to the new one, you need an aditional rewriteRule. Add the following before your existing RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine on


#1)old to new uri handler


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /brand\.php\?brand=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R]
#2)Your new to old uri handler
```

This will externally redirect **/brand.php?brand=brandname** to **/brandname/** .

Comment: Thank you, this works! But now I get a 404 not found... Instead of the output of brands.php

Comment: I was able to fix it, I will post my answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
RewriteRule path/brand.php?brand=(.*)/ path/$1/
```